# Python For Loop Homework

Tags: python, list, for-loop

So this question isn't hard by any means but just worded in a confusing way. I've tried 3 solutions, and none of them are correct. I've given my genuine effort, so I hope someone else can help me out here. Here's the question:

> Using a `for` loop, write the following program: all the two-digit numbers which are equal to double the product of the digits that make up the given number are displayed in a column."

Here are the 3 solutions I've tried so far:

1.

```
num = int(input("Enter a two-digit number: "))
digitArr = []

for i in str(num):
    digitArr.append(i)

result = 1

for j in digitArr:
    result = result * int(j)
result = result ** 2 #here

for i in range(10, 100):
    tempDigitArr = []
    for j in str(i):
        tempDigitArr.append(j)
    tempResult = 1
    for k in tempDigitArr:
        tempResult = tempResult * int(k)
    tempResult = tempResult ** 2 #here
    if tempResult == result:
        print(i)
        tempResult = 1
        continue
    else:
        tempResult = 1
        continue
```

2. 

```
num = int(input("Enter a two-digit number: "))
digitArr = []

for i in str(num):
    digitArr.append(i)

result = 1

for j in digitArr:
    result = result * int(j)
result = result ** 2 #here

for i in range(10, 100):
    tempDigitArr = []
    for j in str(i):
        tempDigitArr.append(j)
    tempResult = 1
    for k in tempDigitArr:
        tempResult = tempResult * int(k)
    tempResult = tempResult ** 2 #here
    if tempResult == result:
        print(i)
        tempResult = 1
        continue
    else:
        tempResult = 1
        continue
```

3. 

```
num = int(input("Enter a two-digit number: "))
digitArr = []

for i in str(num):
    digitArr.append(i)

result = 1

for j in digitArr:
    result = result * int(j)

for i in range(10, 100):
    tempDigitArr = []
    for j in str(i):
        tempDigitArr.append(j)
    tempResult = 1
    for k in tempDigitArr:
        tempResult = tempResult * int(k)
    if tempResult == result:
        print(i)
        tempResult = 1
        continue
    else:
        tempResult = 1
        continue
```

And yes, if anyone's wondering; my course is using an auto-check system ;-;

Comment: Please add the accepted solution as an answer in the space below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methodology is pretty straightforward

```
test = range(10,99+1)

for num in test:

    prod = 1
    for digit in str(num): prod = prod * int(digit)

    if num == 2*prod:
        print(num)
```

Fun fact: only 36 qualifies for this requirement

Comment: `range(10,99)` is not correct, the upper bound is not inclusive, so this will only loop up to `98` (not really relevant here, but in general)

Comment: @tobias_k thanks for that catch, but yeah in principle it doesn't mean anything

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want:

```
for i in range(10, 100):
    tens, units = divmod(i, 10)
    if tens*units*2 == i:
        print(i)
```

Comment: It's just printing out 36 regardless of the input you give it

Comment: From the way your question is framed, you don't need any `input`. You should just be printing *all* two digit numbers that satisfy the condition and 36 is the only one.

Comment: Well, autocorrect isn't accepting this as an answer. I'm pretty sure the question's wording is just literal trash, it probably means something else

Comment: Yeah - unfortunately, without further details, I doubt anyone will be able to understand what your professor actually means/needs. You should probably email them and ask for clearer instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not giving you code (others did so already anyway) but rather explain what (I think) is wrong with your program:

- you say the program is auto-graded, but the question does not say anything about input, so I guess that by expecting `input` your program just waits forever for input that is never provided; instead you probably just need the `for num in range(10, 100)` loop at the bottom
- *if* you do the same calculation twice (which you do not need, see above, but if), you should define a function using `def`, not copy the code
- the question asks about the number being *double* the product of its digits, not the *square*, i.e.use `*2`, not `**2`
- and you should compare that double-product to the number *itself*, not to the product of that first (not asked for) input-number
- since you know it's a *two-digit* number, you do not actually have to loop over the digits but can access them directly using integer(!)-division `//` and modulo `%`

I'm sure you'll get it right with those hints (and without just copying the full code).

Comment: Or `divmod` instead of `//` and `%` :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the requirement correctly, the given number is to be obtained from the user and the two digit numbers have to match it (not themselves):

```
number = int(input("given number: "))

for n in range(10,100):
    d,u = divmod(n,10)
    if d*u*2 == number:
        print(n)
```

Sample run:

```
given number: 36
29
36
63
92
```